# Using len function in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

For a particular data frame, I need to get the number of females hence I used the following code.

```
 f = df.loc[df['Sex']== 'female' ,'Sex']
 print(len(f))
    >>>314
```

But I need to get the length of several other items hence I tried to make a function to calculate the length and put extracted values in it. The code is as follows:

```
def count_num(i):
   k = len(i)
   return k
mf = m.apply(count_num)
print(mf)
>>> But I am getting an output as:
1      6
2      6
3      6
8      6
9      6
10     6
11     6
Name: Sex, Length: 314, dtype: int64
and so on...till the end
```

What changes should be made in the function?

Comment: you don't want to use `apply`. Note, the function you wrote is exactly equivalent to `m.apply(len)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df['Sex'].value_counts()
```

It seems you need:

```
cols = ['col1','col2','Sex']
df1 = df[cols].stack().value_counts()
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':list('accddd'),
                   'Sex':['Female'] * 2 + ['Male'] * 4,
                   'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
                   'col2':list('gggtrr')})

print (df)
   C  D  E     Sex col1 col2
0  7  1  5  Female    a    g
1  8  3  3  Female    c    g
2  9  5  6    Male    c    g
3  4  7  9    Male    d    t
4  2  1  2    Male    d    r
5  3  0  4    Male    d    r

cols = ['col1','col2','Sex']
df1 = df[cols].stack().value_counts()
print (df1)
Male      4
g         3
d         3
c         2
r         2
Female    2
a         1
t         1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Yes, Sir, our answer is correct, but can you please suggest what changes should I make in the function so it calculates the length of any number of items from different columns.Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: @Alen - Can you add sample data?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use group by size. If you have a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['sex'] = ['F','M','F','M','F','M','N','N']
counts = df.groupby('sex').size()
counts['N']
```

Output : `2`